# Catalog promotions - Discount appear in product list but not in product view

Tags: product, catalog, product-list, promotions, products-view

I’ve applied some promotions to my products. After few days applied the promotions disappear in the product view page but remains in the product list.

For example, in the list, the promotions appear:

```
http://195.77.172.19/magento/index.php/smartphones
```

But in the product view, the promotions don’t appear:

```
http://195.77.172.19/magento/index.php/apple-iphone-5
```

The version it’s a clean magento 1.8.0.0. The problem appear few days after applying the promotion.

Any help would be apreciated, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, now I'm really scared. I worked on the same issue 3 days ago. What were the odds?
*This may be the reason:* Because the promotions (and special prices) can be set to have a time limit, the product prices need to be rebuilt each day, to check if the promo price is still available.
*This seams to work for me*: I didn't have the cron setup for my magento instance. (Rookie mistake that I'm ashamed of admitting).  Add this to your crontab:

```
*/10 * * * * php -q /path/to/magento/instance/cron.php
```

Comment: Thanks Marius, but is so strange that the discount appear in product list but no in product view, no? the crontab is in the magento admin?

Comment: Actually is not strange that you see the discount in the list. There you see values from the price index table. I assume your indexes are not automatically built every day. So nothing changes them (same scenario for me). As for crontab, I mean the system crontab. If your OS is linux just type in the command line `crontab -e` and put the line I mentioned in the file that opens up.

Comment: Thanks Marius. Have you added something to cron.php? I've seen some people adding this:                         $observ = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/observer'); 
$observ->dailyCatalogUpdate("0 1 * * *");

Comment: @xavierang. I've seen that also on the web. I didn't modify the `cron.php` file. But you can try it. Whatever solves your issue.

Comment: This is day-one stuff, Marius. I'm shocked.

Comment: @philwinkle. I know. That's why I'm ashamed of admitting it. "S...tuff happens". Against all appearances, I'm only human :)